# NodeJS with arangojs and sync: Everything after .sync() ignored?

Tags: node.js, synchronization, sequential, arangodb

I want to use NodeJS to read 60k records from a MySQL database and write them to a ArangoDB database. I will later use ArangoDB's aggregation features etc. to process my dataset.

Coming from PHP, where a script usually runs synchronous, and because I believe it makes sense here, my initial (naive) try was to make my NodeJS script run sync too. However, it doesn't work as expected:

I print to console, call a function via `.sync()` to connect to ArangoDB server and print all existing databases, then print to console again. But everything below the sync call to my ArangoDB function is completely ignored (does not print to console again, nor does it seem to execute anything else here).

What am I overlooking? Does `.done()` in the function called via `.sync()` cause trouble?

```
var mysql = require('node-mysql');
var arango = require('arangojs');
//var sync = require('node-sync'); // Wrong one!
var sync = require('sync');


function test_arango_query() {
    var db = arango.Connection("http://localhost:8529");
    db.database.list().done(function(res) {
        console.log("Databases: %j", res);
    });
    return "something?";
}

sync(function() {
    console.log("sync?");
    var result = test_arango_query.sync();
    console.log("done."); // DOES NOT PRINT, NEVER EXECUTED?!
    return result;

}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `test_arango_query` doesn't use a callback. `sync` only works with functions that use a callback. It needs to know when the data is ready to return it from `.sync()`, if your function never calls the callback, then `sync` can't ever return a result.

Update your function to call a callback function when you want it to return:

```
function test_arango_query(callback) {
    var db = arango.Connection("http://localhost:8529");
    db.database.list().done(function(res) {
        console.log("Databases: %j", res);
        callback('something');
    });
}
```

Comment: Makes sense and was one easy fix. Thank you so much! Your explanation should be the first paragraph of the `sync` readme, really. It seems to lack very basic examples that focus on the core concept.

Comment: I wonder however, why NodeJS terminates immediately after the arangodb query using my original code. If my `test_arango_query()` function never returns, and it's called synchronous, shouldn't that make NodeJS hang forever?

Comment: @CoDEmanX Your function does return. It returns immediately though, way before the query completes. If you want to know when that data is ready, you need to use a `callback`, and because of that I don't think the `sync` library is doing much for you. `node.js` is designed to be very asynchronous, and that is great! With a language like PHP, you have a set number of processes, say 20, and if they're all waiting for some slow query to wait, then other uses can't even load simple pages.

Comment: @CoDEmanX With only one process and thread in `node.js`, all 20 queries could be running, but your server doesn't block, so it can keep serving requests to other users at the same time. It's pretty cool.

Comment: @CoDEmanX If you are going to be using much `node.js` I would have to advise you to avoid the `sync` library and learn the asynchronous way of doing things. Read about the `event loop` in Javascript and then read about how Promises work, and take a look at the `bluebird` Promise library. It's really nice!

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, I'll check out bluebird. I should definately make use of asynchronicity, and I will as soon as time allows. But for my current project, I might even run my script client-side only (=in browser). Shouldn't be too bad, as my dataset is nowhere near Big data and it's an offline task anyway.